# Producer Consumer issue in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

```
public class SomeAdaptor implements SomeListener {

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double> pendingRFQ; 

    @Override
    public void run() {
       pendingRFQ.put(response.getId(), price);
    } //first run method

    @Override
    public void run() {
         Double price = pendingRFQ.get(quoteEvent.getId());
         if (price != null)
            System.out.println("ORDER TO Market.....");
    } //2nd run method
```

I am having some threading issue. The `pendingRFQ` map is not up to date, when I try to extract the price in the 2nd `run()` method. What techniques can I execute in 2nd `run()` method to make sure the value I'm looking up is present?  Or how can I make it wait till it comes in?

Comment: You can't have two methods with the same name and signature in the same class. That is, you can't have two run methods in the same class. Also you're missing quite a few `}`.

Comment: Producer/Consumer generally has the consumer thread wait/block until there is something available.  When the producer produces something, it can then notify a waiting/blocking consumer thread that something is available.

Comment: You have a public class with a public field.  My guess is that you're pretty new at concurrent programming.

Answer (score 6):

Replace the `Map` with a `BlockingQueue` and use `poll()` in the second thread to wait for input.

Comment: +1 `ArrayBlockingQueue` is a good impl to use.  If you need the map for something else then just add the queue for the thread communication.